# $(...).dialog is not a function while opening popup on button click event

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui, popup

Already i got answer for this. But when i workout i got this error on console.log(). I don't know what is the issue. Here is my jsfiddle link [jsfiddlelink](https://jsfiddle.net/Lu6fnrrt/)

This is my html code.I have created one button to open dialog and one div for the popup dialog.

```
<button id="opener">Cick to open</button>
<div id="dialog1" title="Dialog Title" hidden="hidden">dialog Opened</div>
```

This is my script to trigger popup on clicking the button

```
$(document).ready(function() 
{
   $( "#dialog1" ).dialog(
   {
    autoOpen: false
   });

   $("#opener").click(function()
   {
    $("#dialog1").dialog('open');
   });
});
```

Comment: have you included the required script?

Comment: yeah i have added from jquery site

Comment: Note that `.dialog()` is from [jQuery UI](https://jqueryui.com/dialog/) not regular jQuery ;)

Comment: you should include jqueryui library  https://jsfiddle.net/Lu6fnrrt/5/

Comment: yeah i tried that also i have downloaded that jquery alone and worked out .. but its showing this error alone ..

Comment: please help me to get solve this.

Comment: You have to **load jQuery first** see https://jsfiddle.net/DelightedDoD/Lu6fnrrt/4/

Comment: its working on your fiddle, but my doubt is i too added the links as external resources in my fiddle..Is there any wrong in my fiddle

Comment: Yes, in your fiddle, jQuery UI is loaded first, that is incorrect, you must load jQuery **then load jQuery UI** . They are loaded in the order they are listed there from top to bottom just as they would be if they were links in your html file

Comment: oh got it.. i thought that won't be a problem .. since we are loading the scripts in our head tag right? Thanks a lot to mention my mistake ..

Comment: @DelightedD0D i got the same issue again while working in my vs2013. where i have loaded the scripts as you said.

Comment: Something is not loaded properly, thats about the only thing that could cause that error. Check your console, are there any 404 errors or anything?

Comment: i have copied all scripts and css from that link to my folder. After this its working but the images are not loading properly stating this error **Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)**